# Python glob return empty array, why?

Tags: python, glob

I have this simple Python code which supposed to return files in path. But it returns an empty list all the time. Why ?
My array path is correct.

```
import glob
flowers_path = 'C:/flower_v1/training-images/*/*.jpg'
addrs = glob.glob(flowers_path)
print(addrs)
```

Returns :

```
[]
```

My directory structure :
[image]

I am doing the execution on Google Collab.

Comment: Why do you expect an empty string? What do you think glob does?

Comment: Because that's what [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) does: it returns a list, which can be empty.

Comment: It should not return empty as my directories and not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't quite getting the `glob` syntax right. You should try this:

```
import glob

flowers_path = 'C:/flower_v1/training-images/**/*.jpg' # ** is for going through directories
address = glob.glob(flowers_path, recursive=True)  # recursive flag must be true

print(address)
```

or simply

```
address = glob.glob('/**/*.jpg',recursive=True)
```

Comment: This is quite speculative. The OP's attempt is not clearly wrong, though it is of course possible that you happened to guess what their problem is.

Comment: It still returns empty. I updated my question with the directory structure as well.

Comment: FOund the issue. This works fine including my original on Jupiter notebooks on my PC. But it fails on Google Collab.

Comment: @PCG clarify... the images are on your PC, but you're executing on Google Colab? You need to upload the images to Colab. Your code is running in the cloud, not on your PC.

Comment: I have the same problem, however `recursive=True` doesn't help. Is there any other solution?